# Can not connect to SSL enabled ASE-Sybase 16 Using ADO.NET Data Provider

Tags: ssl, ado.net, sap-ase

I am working on .NET web application. I try to connect to database in SSL enabled Adaptive Server Enterprise (Sybase 16) using Sybase.Data.AseClient dll. Connection string that I am using is `'Provider=Sybase.Ase;DataSource='IP';Port='5000';UID='user';PWD='password';Database='database';Encryption=ssl;TrustedFile='c:\\Sybase\\ini\\trusted.txt';'`. When Application tries to connect to database exception is thrown. 'Client can not establish connection'.

By the way in Embarcadero i can connecto to the database without any issues, sql.ini entry as below
[host]

```
master=TCP,IP,5000,ssl
query=TCP,IP,5000,ssl
```

Note: trusted.txt file is recevied from DB Server administrator

Answer (score 0):

the problem was i was using an old dll, i should use Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll instead of Sybase.Data.AseClient.dll